# Load frontend model class in admin controller in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to load a model class which is in frontend(catalog/model/account/address) in admin controller. I can do it by copying that model to admin's model folder but I want to do it without copying model class.

Is there is any way to do it? or I have to modify the loader class. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I've posted a solution here on the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/23020160/2002127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address methods are available in the catalog side via the `admin/model/sale/customer.php` file in the admin. Simply use that instead

```
$this->load->model('sale/customer');
$addresses = $this->model_sale_customer->getAddresses(12345);
```

Comment: thanks..I am new to opencart that's why I don't have knowledge of all models..really helped..